# How to use UseEffect every time get user and axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I use MERN stack and redux. I have two problem and please help me. 
**1)** Every component react I add this:

```
const user = useSelector( state => state.user );
  useEffect( ()=>{
     dispatch(User_Auth(12)) ; // I write 12 for action work. 
  });
```

I want to get user data every time if user loginned or not. Is it true? or some idea have?

**2)** In backend if data current I send using 200 status codes. another variant I send data other status like this:

```
router.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.user.isAuth = true;
        res.status(200).json(req.user);
    }
    else{
        return res.status(401).json({
            isAuth: false
        });
    }
});
```

This is my action get User data:

```
export const User_Auth =   (value) => async (dispatch) => {
    value = value + 0;
    await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url:'http://localhost:3001/api/users/auth',
        withCredentials:true
    })
    .then(res => {
        
        dispatch({type: user_auth, payload: res.data});
    }).catch(error => {
        // console.log("Auth geldim: ", error);
    });
}
```

I want if cannot see errors in console.log browser. Can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about the question. It's kind of blur to me. Can you explain in short what you want

Comment: I want cannot see errors in console tab chrome. for example if backend send 401 http status error I see only console log tab but can I clear that using when use axios catch

Comment: Do you mean that you want to clear the console data from your code?

Comment: i want to control errors in code

Comment: You want to do something in the catch block based on the errors?

Comment: If I send incorrect data in login page , login page I do this: res.status(401).json({ messgase:  "Invalid email or password" }). I want to see this message in error my component but it doent be. Only i see console tab chrome - Request failed with status code 401

Comment: I want to what I send error backend to frontend ( to  axios ) I get this. But I cant get it. Why I dont know. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the status code from an error you have to access it like this

```
error.status
```

And to get the message

```
error.message
```